# My Visualization is not clear - the subfigures are breaking in

Tags: python, matplotlib

How Can I Solve This Problem :

[image]
the code is:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(24,12))
sns.scatterplot(data =df,x='Open',y='Close')

for index,col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if col =='Close':
        continue
    plt.subplot(2,2,index+1)
    plt.title(f'The Scatter Plot Between {col} and Close Price')
    sns.scatterplot(data=df,x=col,y='Close')
```

I Did Try Change the values of figsize but i couldn't solve the problem

Comment: The call to `sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='Open',y='Close')` outside the loop creates a large subplot.  You could consider removing that call.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is that you are first creating a figure (and thereby also an axis object). Then, on top of that, you are creating a number of subplots.

The solution is to create a number of subplots and then to plot into them. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# just some example data ...
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Open': np.linspace(0, 1, 100),
    'Close': np.linspace(0, 10, 100) + np.random.rand(100),
    'X1': np.linspace(0, 1, 100),
    'X2': np.linspace(0, 1, 100),
})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(24,12))
ax = axes.ravel()  # ax is now a 1d-array of all subplot-axes

sns.scatterplot(data =df,x='Open',y='Close', color='red', ax=ax[1])  # upper right subplot

for index,col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if col =='Close':
        continue
    ax[index].set_title(f'The Scatter Plot Between {col} and Close Price')
    sns.scatterplot(data=df,x=col,y='Close', ax=ax[index])
```

which would result in the following plot:

[image]

Note, that for convenience, I turned the 2x2 array `axes` (which contains the 2x2 subplots) into a 1D array with 4 "axis elements". This makes indexing the subplots a little bit easier. Hope that helps.